# Intellij Language Injection for babel less

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration

I'm trying to add language injection for IntelliJ IDEA as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065100/switching-between-languages-in-same-file) question.

We use `<@less> ... </@less>` markup for including less into template files which contain HTML and I'd like to have the less in that block syntax highlighted. The template file is *.ftl* and is treated as HTML (when I put `<style type="text/css"> ... </style>` around that `<@less>` tag, it is highlighted as css).

So far I tried this, but no luck:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Injection into FreeMarker macro calls will be available in the upcoming release of IDEA. Please see a blog post including a description of this feature: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/01/intellij-idea-starts-2018-1-early-access-program/, there's also a link to download the preview there.

Comment: So the reason is that I'm trying to put the injection into FreeMarker macro (sorry, I'm newbie into FreeMarker). Thank you very much for explanation and for that link which looks very optimistic.